# how to bind php variable to mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have MySQL join query and I want bind it with php variable. How can I do that?
I have tried to bind it by calling the variable of php and place it in MySQL query but I'm getting an error

```
$query = "SELECT p.temp,p.date,"pp."".$selectedSensorOption.",pp.date FROM `p1` p inner join p2 pp on p.date = pp.date and date(p.date) between '$dateFrom2' and '$dateTo2' and date(pp.date) between '$dateFrom2' and '$dateTo2'";     
$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);

if (! empty($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
?>
<tbody id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $result[$key][0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[$key][1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[$key][2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[$key][3]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[$key][4]; ?></td>
    </tr> 
<?php
```

since its join table I want to bind php variable of MySQL to php variable

Comment: What does your error say?

Comment: What is `pp` in `$query = "SELECT p.temp,p.date,"pp."".$selectedSensorOption." ...` ? It seems to be set as a var bu without `$`

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensor\DBController.php on line 18

Comment: There is no `mysqli_num_rows()` in your code. But it means the query couldn't be executed. The error is probably generated inside your `$db_handle->runQuery()` call.

Comment: i did join two tables p1 and p2 so i assigned variable for each of them such as p1 p and p2 pp

Comment: i want the column to be dynamic from php variable

Comment: To check your query use `echo $query;` just after you made it. Does that look right?

Comment: there isn't problem with the way you want to go, but either `runQuery()` don't work as expected or the typo `,"pp."` doesn't help, but i guess you did not copy paste

Comment: I don't know what `runQuery()` is but you might want to take a look at PHP's `PDO` extension (which gets shipped with almost every PHP distribution by default). It has the possibility to bind a param to a query using https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your query is wrong : please try below

`$query = "SELECT p.temp,p.date,pp.".$selectedSensorOption.",pp.date FROM p1 p inner join p2 pp on p.date = pp.date and date(p.date) between '$dateFrom2' and '$dateTo2' and date(pp.date) between '$dateFrom2' and '$dateTo2'";

$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);`